# How to change the text color in a Materializecss select dropdown?

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I have a Materializecss dropdown select like this:

```
      <form class="col s12">
        <select id="something" [ngModel]="_model.selectedPartyType"
            (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange($event)" name="partyTypeSelection"
            materialize="material_select" class="input-field col s12 m12 l4"
            >
           <optgroup *ngFor="let data of _model.codeTable.codeTokensG" [label]="data[0]">
             <option *ngFor="let cValue of data[1]" [value]="cValue">
               {{_model.codeTable.getCode(cValue).description}}
        </   option>
           </optgroup>
       </select>
      </form>
```

how do I change the default teal color for the option text? I have tried adding

```
.dropdown-content li>span {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.dropdown-content li>a {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.select-content li>span {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.select-content li>a {
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

to my css file, but no luck with this and variants. If I deselect the color attribute in Chrome Developer Tools for the

```
.dropdown-content li>span
```

is does as I wish.

How can I change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jquery Single line solution**

```
 $(".dropdown-content>li>a").css("color", themeColor);
```

You can change color dynamically to any color of your choice

**Live Demo**

See the Pen [Materialize CSS Change Theme Color](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/EXoPRq/) by Hitesh  Sahu ([@hiteshsahu](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: This doesn't use the `select` form element at all.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem today. Here's how I solved it:

```
ul.dropdown-content.select-dropdown li span {
    color: #000; /* no need for !important :) */
}
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me, the text's color stays as the default blue..

Comment: To ensure disabled aren't affected I used:

`ul.dropdown-content.select-dropdown li:not(.disabled) span {
    color: #1976d2;
}`

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me

```
/* Dropdown list color */

.dropdown-content li > a, .dropdown-content li > span {
    color: #fb8c00 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this will change the **select** tag :

```
.select-dropdown{
    color: #000;
}
```

this will change the **option** tag :

```
ul.dropdown-content.select-dropdown li span {
    color: #000; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

works on materialize css version 1.0.0

```
ul.dropdown-content li a {
    color: #000; /* no need for !important :) */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't able to run your code but i copy pasted the dropdown code form the site and applied `blue-text` class to it.

**HTML:**

```
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li> <a href="#!" class = "blue-text">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Did your try applying a text class to your option element?

Comment: weird..this answer is working for me and your accepted answer isn't :/ but I'm still not interested in adding a class to every href I have. any ideas?

Comment: @wadie I would suggest you to look at the dropdown elements' hierarchy in developer's console in chrome. If you dont want to add class to every href element, the most upvoted one answer is the way to go, just check the hierarchy and class names.

Comment: @LarsNielsen This should work. Just be sure it's "blue-text" and not "text-blue". I mix that up very often.